# Evaluate the following integral $\iiint1$

Tags: calculus, integration

Calculate the $\iiint 1$ of the region $A=\{(x,y,z):1\leq x^2+y^2+z^2\leq4, y\geq0\}$.

I made $\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}\leq z\leq \sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}$, $\sqrt{1-x^2} \leq y \leq \sqrt{4-x^2}$, $1\leq x\leq 2$. And obtained $\int_{1}^{2}\int_{\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{4-x^2}}\int_{\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}1dA$. I wanted to ask, is this correct?

Comment: Are you allowed to use spherical coordinates?

Comment: No it is not correct, when $x^2 + y^2 \leq 1 ~$ for example, what are the bounds of $z$? It is easier in spherical coordinates. Are you familiar with it?

Comment: Little tip: The volume should be that of a half ball with radius $2$ with a ball of radius 1 removed so $1/2 \cdot 4/3\pi(2^3-1^3) = 14/3\pi$. Or using Montecarlo integration: https://sagecell.sagemath.org/

Comment: Ain’t I stupid? I copied the wrong link... https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxTVqg4tEm7EoirDm2ysTVRyMwtyMlMLVaoqajRqakE4qoaG1sjXi5eLj8FWwVDAxDg5YoAsotK8zLTNPx0FHSNdBSMNHm5IpEFDUBiCsoKkQp2tgpAHVHYdIT4hzj6xDsGuToCZU20jLRMeLky8-KT8kvzUoqBQhoRWlpGCtoKkRAqCkQBjTPUVFDDKmcDNAVobJBrsG1uamKeBtwsTS2EVbxcyRpAFToKQEK_IFPLWBMA-AdCtQ==&lang=r&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==
Anyway. Montecarlo integration is a good method to verify such results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are simply evaluating the volume between two spheres centered at the origin.

That integral should evaluate to $\frac{4}{3}\pi r_2^3 - \frac{4}{3}\pi r_1^3=\frac{4}{3}\pi(64-1)=84\pi$